# Sound not stopped if start "on create" void

Tags: android, audio, android-activity

```
public class Form1 extends ActionBarActivity { private MediaPlayer mp; Context context; ... setContentView(R.layout.activity_form1);

    if (mp==null) {
        context = this;
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.drawable.mainmenus);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    };
.... public void startbook(View view) {

      mp.pause();
      mp.stop();
      mp.reset();
      mp.release();
      mp = null;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Form1.this, Form2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If press button "startbook", sound not stop.

Comment: remove mp.reset() from the method and check.

Comment: I already touched all possible combinations. A problem in other. If  i am add to code: public void startplay(View view) { mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.drawable.mainmenus);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();}, whent code:  public void startbook(View view) {
      mp.stop();
      mp = null;} is work! ((

Comment: Correct code as good:  public static MediaPlayer mp= null

Answer (score 0):

Correct code as good: public static MediaPlayer mp= null